A guide to using "amsbook"
I am going to write my PhD thesis. There are templates (eg, 1 and 2) for other classes with detailed code samples about Abstract > Acknowledgements > ToC > List of Abbreviations > List of Figures > List of Tables > Chapters > Appendices.
But would like to to use the class amsbook. Unfortunately, I could not find any material about how to format according to amsbook. The closest thing I have is its documentation which is about the underlying code of the package and not about how to use it.

Are there materials about how to use amsbook properly? Examples with snippets of thesis/book using amsbook would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your elaboration.

Start here  https://www.ams.org/arc/handbook/handbook-mono.pdf

You can also search the ams website for author guide, it will bring additional resouces for journals etc. IMHO though unless you prublishing with the AMS is better to use say a thesis class and modify accordingly. The style guide though is a must read.

@yannisl Thank you for your suggestion. Do you have some "thesis class" in mind?

I am not too sure what is a good thesis class, as most are written for specific institutions. If I had to write a thesis today though I would choose, either book, or scrbook, and use LuaLaTeX, ams packages etc,  and bibLaTeX  for references. Why? You can start writing on day1, you will be able to use system fonts, so you wouldnt be running around to find out how to print that Japanese paper you have in your bibliography etc.
